# How to divide up 'supply' evenly among rows in a dataframe by rank in Python?

Tags: python

Ex. if I have 'supply' of 10, how can I distribute this evenly in a dataframe so that each row gets 1 until the 'supply' is depleted? Each row must get 1 before the first ranked row can get another. Below is the output I'm looking to achieve.

```
data = [['1','2','10'],['2','2','10'],['3','2','10'],['4','1','10'],['5','1','10'],['6','1','10'],['7','1','10']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['rank','allocation','supply'])

| rank | allocation | supply |
|:---- |:---------- |:------ |
| 1    |  2         | 10     |
| 2    |  2         | 10     |
| 3    |  2         | 10     |
| 4    |  1         | 10     |
| 5    |  1         | 10     |
| 6    |  1         | 10     |
| 7    |  1         | 10     |
```

Comment: Please post your output inline, without links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple strategy would be to construct your supply column as a list accordingly and assign it to your dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(100)) # example
supply_num = 10
supply_col = ([1] * supply_num) + ([0] * (df.shape[0] - supply_num))
df['supply'] = supply_col
print(df)
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this solves your issue, accept the answer so that the question can be tagged as answered?